# php code not converting gmt to ist properly

Tags: php

This is a very small issue yet i am not able to solve it

i wish to convert gmt to ist through php, for this i have the following code

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Tue, 17 Dec 2013 07:23:56 +0000');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
echo date('r', $timestamp);
```

the code is working properly, now i have an array through which i have fetched time which is in this format

```
10-Dec-2015 10:45:02 +0000
```

i have stored in a variable  $maildate

Now when i am placing this variable in the code like this

```
$timestamp = strtotime('$maildate');
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
echo date('r', $timestamp);
```

i am getting this date and time `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 05:30:00 +0530`

can anyone please tell where i am going wrong

Comment: `'$maildate'` is the literal string `$maildate`. Get rid of the quotes.

Comment: @Jon Stirling on removing the quotes i get a syntax error

Comment: "i get a syntax error" - [norepo](https://3v4l.org/FO11Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of quotes and update your code from

```
$timestamp = strtotime('$maildate');
                      ^^         ^^
```

into

```
$timestamp = strtotime($maildate);
                    //^^        ^^ Removed quotes
```

Instead you can use `DateTime` class like as

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y H:i:s P',$var);
$date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
echo $date->format('r');
```

Comment: Leaving the DateTime example would be nice too. DateTime++

Answer (score 0):

Check out this

```
$timestamp = strtotime($maildate);
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
echo date('r', $timestamp);
```